# jQuery ui autocomplete combobox - default value when user enters non valid value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, combobox

EDIT: Doh! I should have placed my code here too! Here it is:

My code to call the combobox:

```
jQuery( "#select_performance" ).combobox();
jQuery( "#select_state" ).combobox();
jQuery( "#select_postcode" ).combobox();
jQuery( "#select_install" ).combobox();
jQuery( "#select_customer" ).combobox();
jQuery( "#select_address" ).combobox();
```

My code (as is from JQuery ui) to define the fields:

```
/*** Set up multiselect drop down lists ***/
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
                .insertAfter( this.element );

            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
        },

        _createAutocomplete: function() {
            var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

            this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .val( value )
                .attr( "title", "" )
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
                })
                .tooltip({
                    tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                }).on('mouseup', function() {
                    $(this).select();
                });

            this._on( this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    this._trigger( "select", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
        },

        _createShowAllButton: function() {
            var input = this.input,
                wasOpen = false;

            $( "<a>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                .tooltip()
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
                .mousedown(function() {
                    wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
                })
                .click(function() {
                    input.focus();

                    // Close if already visible
                    if ( wasOpen ) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                });
        },

        _source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
            response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                var text = $( this ).text();
                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                    return {
                        label: text,
                        value: text,
                        option: this
                    };
            }) );
        },

        _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if ( ui.item ) {
                return;
            }

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
                valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                valid = false;
            this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if ( valid ) {
                return;
            }

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input
                .val( "" )
                .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
                .tooltip( "open" );
            this.element.val( "" );
            this._delay(function() {
                this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
            }, 2500 );
            this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
        },

        _destroy: function() {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

I have 6 jQuery autocomplete comboboxes on a page. Each has selected a default item set up on load (first item of the list). When a user types in an invalid entry, (or blanks the input box) I get the tooltip saying "invalid entry". Is there a way to have the value be re-set to the initially selected / default entry (first list item)?

I cannot seem to find the answer to this (or perhaps I am asking the wrong way).

Thanks!

Comment: Where in your code do you set the default value?

Comment: Hi codesmith, I set the default value in the actual HTML. I build the select entries via Javascript by pulling these from a MySql db. he first entry in the Select list is "All Postcodes" (for example) and it is set by the JS that builds the element.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're setting your default value but here's a clue of how to go about it.

```
      change: function (event, ui) {
          if (ui.item === null) { // if value typed in the box doesn't exist then
              $(this).val(""); // set value to empty string
              $(this).val(list[0]).data('autocomplete')._trigger('select'); set new value here and then trigger reset. Assuming list is your array of items, select the first item
          }
      }
```

Comment: hi dcodesmith, thanks for the answer. I am building the lists from a MySql db via server script, so I do not have an array as such. How do I address the first item (my default / selected on page load) directly from the combobox list itself? Thanks!!